# I already heard filtering the air to get rid of the Virus is not that effective but what about UV radiation?

Tags: virology

Why they don't add a chamber to their air conditions and give the air treatment with UV radiation? I'm not a science guy. Please what might be the reason? Wouldn't it be also cheaper because the air conditions don't need to pressure the air through tiny filters?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a forum or tutorial service; it is a Q&A site where *specific* questions relating to biology get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask] a good question. See also the section on "homework".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UV is highly effective against many viruses and bacteria . [It needs to be germidicidal UV](https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/coronavirus-covid-19-and-medical-devices/uv-lights-and-lamps-ultraviolet-c-radiation-disinfection-and-coronavirus), often known as UV-C in the short UV wavelengths, so there is no doubt that this could work (indeed there are a number of people working on it at the moment, and even some devices available). This sort of technology has been in place in healthcare settings for disinfecting patient rooms for immunocompromised cancer patients for example.

The difficulty with this is providing enough UV to the air-flow so that it deactivates the virus during the short time the virus is passing the UV bulbs. There's a good source of information at the Illumination Engineering Society about UV and germicidal activity [here](https://media.ies.org/docs/standards/IES-CR-2-20-V1-6d.pdf) (PDF), which specifically discusses SARS-CoV-2 and the mechanics of how to do it. It discusses in terms of air-changes-per-hour (ACH) and dose for a number of situations:

> ... simpler evidence-based dose that has been developed over many
> years for TB control, typically specified as about 17 mW of 254-nm lamp-emission radiant power per cubic meter (m<sup>3</sup>) of space to disinfect air.

17 milliWatts of power might not seem like much given that your room lights probably use between 5-200 Watts per bulb, but they are putting out a broad range of light (mostly as heat) from about 400 nm to 800 nm, but the UV bulb output that is being measured here is the specific germicidal wavelength of 254 nm, overall the lamps put out much more light than that and are enormously energy hungry.

It also says that disinfecting the volume above people in a room is more effective than irradiating incoming (or presumably outgoing) air because of the risk of person-person transmission with people in the same room:

> Upper-room GUV (see Figure 3-1) disinfects large volumes of room air (above occupants’ heads) at once,
> resulting in high "equivalent" air changes per hour (ACH) in terms of air disinfection only...
>
> ...When UV is used in ducts, although it ensures that recirculated air does not have viable pathogens, it
> unfortunately does relatively little to prevent person-to-person transmission in a room where both an
> infectious source and other susceptible persons share the same air. For effective interruption of
> transmission, air disinfection has to occur in the same room where transmission is occurring